# RuntimeError: tf.placeholder() is not compatible with eager execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have upgraded with tf_upgrade_v2 TF1 code to TF2. I'm a noob with both. I got the next error:

```
RuntimeError: tf.placeholder() is not compatible with eager execution.
```

I have some `tf.compat.v1.placeholder()`.

```
self.temperature = tf.compat.v1.placeholder_with_default(1., shape=())
self.edges_labels = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(dtype=tf.int64, shape=(None, vertexes, vertexes))
self.nodes_labels = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(dtype=tf.int64, shape=(None, vertexes))
self.embeddings = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, embedding_dim))
```

Could you give me any advice about how to proceed? Any "fast" solutions? or should I to recode this?

Answer (score 111):

I found an easy solution here: [disable Tensorflow eager execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53429896/disable-tensorflow-eager-execution)

Basicaly it is:

`tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()`

With this, you disable the default activate eager execution and you don't need to touch the code much more.

Comment: I don't think doing this is a great idea because you lose out on the ability to interleave python and tensorflow code easily - you are severely restricted in terms of expressiveness and might as well use TF 1.X. If you want to compile operations into graph components while still having eager execution enabled, you can decorate functions with `tf.function` which does a JIT compilation of code into a graph.

Comment: Where do we use this method ? Instead of each tf.compat.v1.placeholder() ?

Comment: At the beginning of the use of TF or script.

Comment: Trying to run some "old" Tensorflow code, and it feels like half the library is deprecated.

Comment: @AMGMNPLK `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()`, thanks~

Answer (score 23):

tf.placeholder() is meant to be fed to the session that when run receive the values from feed dict and perform the required operation.
Generally, you would create a Session() with 'with' keyword and run it. But this might not favour all situations due to which you would require immediate execution. This is called eager execution.
Example:

generally, this is the procedure to run a Session:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def square(num):
    return tf.square(num) 

p = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
q = square(num)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(q, feed_dict={num: 10})
```

But when we run with eager execution we run it as:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()

def square(num):
   return tf.square(num)

print(square(10))
```

Therefore we need not run it inside a session explicitly and can be more intuitive in most of the cases. This provides more of an interactive execution.
For further details visit:
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager

If you are converting the code from tensorflow v1 to tensorflow v2, You must implement tf.compat.v1 and  Placeholder is present at tf.compat.v1.placeholder but this can only be executed in eager mode off.

```
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```

TensorFlow released the eager execution mode, for which each node is immediately executed after definition. Statements using tf.placeholder are thus no longer valid.

Comment: Thanks Ashish. Yes, I understand the logic under eager and session, but I'm talking about upgrading TF1 code to TF2 with the ft_upgrade_v2 tool. Doesn't it take care of the placeholders?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your issue!It seems that placeholders are removed from tensorflow2.0 and you need to create a tensor of type None.Also if you use tf.compat.v1.* then you need to turn off eager execution due to incompatibility!

Comment: `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()`, thanks~

Answer (score 12):

In TensorFlow 1.X, placeholders are created and meant to be fed with actual values when a `tf.Session` is instantiated. However, from TensorFlow2.0 onwards, [Eager Execution](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager) has been enabled by default, so the notion of a "placeholder" does not make sense as operations are computed immediately (rather than being differed with the old paradigm).

Also see [Functions, not Sessions](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/effective_tf2),

```
# TensorFlow 1.X
outputs = session.run(f(placeholder), feed_dict={placeholder: input})
# TensorFlow 2.0
outputs = f(input)
```

Answer (score 12):

If you are getting this error while doing object detection using TensorFlow model then use `exporter_main_v2.py` instead of `export_inference_graph.py` for exporting the model. This is right method to do. If you just off eager_execution then it will solve this error but generate other.

Also note that there are some parameter change like hear you will specify the path to directory of checkpoint instead of path to checkpoint. refer to [this](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html#exporting-a-trained-model) document for how to do object detection with TensorFlow V2

Answer (score 6):

To solve this, you have to disable the default activate eager execution. So add the following code line.

**tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()**  #<--- Disable eager execution

- Before the error fixing
  [image]
- After the error fixing
  [image]