# Tensorflow models tutorial scripts upgrade to v2

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tried to upgrade one of the models' scripts to v2 using [tf_upgrade_v2](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/upgrade) . I tried the [convolutional.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/mnist/convolutional.py) :

```
 tf_upgrade_v2.exe --infile .\convolutional.py --outfile .\convolutional_2.py
```

The conversion report:

```
TensorFlow 2.0 Upgrade Script
-----------------------------
Converted 1 files
Detected 0 issues that require attention
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
================================================================================
Detailed log follows:

================================================================================
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Processing file '.\\convolutional.py'
 outputting to '.\\convolutional_2.py'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

66:9: INFO: Renamed 'tf.gfile.Exists' to 'tf.io.gfile.exists'
67:4: INFO: Renamed 'tf.gfile.MakeDirs' to 'tf.io.gfile.makedirs'
69:9: INFO: Renamed 'tf.gfile.Exists' to 'tf.io.gfile.exists'
71:9: INFO: Renamed 'tf.gfile.GFile' to 'tf.io.gfile.GFile'
154:20: INFO: Renamed 'tf.placeholder' to 'tf.compat.v1.placeholder'
157:22: INFO: Renamed 'tf.placeholder' to 'tf.compat.v1.placeholder'
158:14: INFO: Renamed 'tf.placeholder' to 'tf.compat.v1.placeholder'
166:6: INFO: Renamed 'tf.truncated_normal' to 'tf.random.truncated_normal'
170:30: INFO: Renamed 'tf.truncated_normal' to 'tf.random.truncated_normal'
175:6: INFO: Renamed 'tf.truncated_normal' to 'tf.random.truncated_normal'
180:28: INFO: Renamed 'tf.truncated_normal' to 'tf.random.truncated_normal'
194:11: INFO: Added keywords to args of function 'tf.nn.conv2d'
194:11: INFO: Renamed keyword argument for tf.nn.conv2d from filter to filters
202:11: INFO: Added keywords to args of function 'tf.nn.max_pool'
202:11: INFO: Renamed keyword argument for tf.nn.max_pool from value to input
202:11: INFO: Renamed 'tf.nn.max_pool' to 'tf.nn.max_pool2d'
206:11: INFO: Added keywords to args of function 'tf.nn.conv2d'
206:11: INFO: Renamed keyword argument for tf.nn.conv2d from filter to filters
211:11: INFO: Added keywords to args of function 'tf.nn.max_pool'
211:11: INFO: Renamed keyword argument for tf.nn.max_pool from value to input
211:11: INFO: Renamed 'tf.nn.max_pool' to 'tf.nn.max_pool2d'
227:15: INFO: Changing keep_prob arg of tf.nn.dropout to rate, and recomputing value.

232:9: INFO: Added keywords to args of function 'tf.reduce_mean'
245:18: INFO: tf.train.exponential_decay requires manual check. To use learning rate decay schedules with TensorFlow 2.0, switch to the schedules in `tf.keras.optimizers.schedules`.

245:18: INFO: Renamed 'tf.train.exponential_decay' to 'tf.compat.v1.train.exponential_decay'
252:14: INFO: Renamed 'tf.train.MomentumOptimizer' to 'tf.compat.v1.train.MomentumOptimizer'
286:7: INFO: Renamed 'tf.Session' to 'tf.compat.v1.Session'
288:4: INFO: Renamed 'tf.global_variables_initializer' to 'tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer'
341:2: INFO: Renamed 'tf.app.run' to 'tf.compat.v1.app.run'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However, when I tried to run the converted script, it gave me an error

```
2019-12-06 19:07:33.611809: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_100.dll
Extracting data\train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting data\train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Extracting data\t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting data\t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\convolutional_2.py", line 341, in <module>
    tf.compat.v1.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\platform\app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 299, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 250, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File ".\convolutional_2.py", line 156, in main
    shape=(BATCH_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, NUM_CHANNELS))
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 2627, in placeholder
    raise RuntimeError("tf.placeholder() is not compatible with "
RuntimeError: tf.placeholder() is not compatible with eager execution.
```

So should I do an extra step or there is a converted repo for TensorFlow 2.0 models? Thanks

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56561734/runtimeerror-tf-placeholder-is-not-compatible-with-eager-execution

Comment: @VadimShkaberda it doesn't tell the solution and if you try it, it won't work . Eager execution is disabled and issue is there on all models. I was just looking for upgraded tensorflow 2.0 models but couldn't find it.

Comment: I'm using tf v2.0 1. " Eager execution is disabled" - that's not true. Add `tf.executing_eagerly()` at the beginning of `main` to ensure. 2. Because eager execution is enabled, adding `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()` works. 3. If I incorrectly understand your question, extra steps are here: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate