# By which command tf.placeholder is replaced in tensorflow 2.4?

Tags: tensorflow, attributeerror, tensorflow2

I am using **tensorflow 2.4.1** and a code from **tensorflow 1**. Whenever I run the following command, I get an error

```
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name = 'input')
```

error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-c2404ca8696c> in <module>()
----> 1 inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name = 'input')

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder'
```

Comment: I have tried tf.compat.v1.placeholder() but got a RuntimeError.

Comment: Answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56561734/runtimeerror-tf-placeholder-is-not-compatible-with-eager-execution

Comment: In order to use `tf.placeholder` with Tensorflow 2, follow the code like 
`import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf` and followed by 
`tf.disable_v2_behavior()` then `tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name = 'input')`.

Answer (score 0):

[tf.keras.Input()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Input) is used in place of tf.placeholder() to instantiate a Keras tensor in Tensorflow version 2.x.

Please check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/placeholder) link for more details.