# How much slower is tensorflow 2.0 with eager execution?

Tags: performance, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

In Tensorflow 1 graph mode is faster than eager execution. However, Tensorflow 2.0 comes with [eager execution enabled by default](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/eager), and [evidently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55938423/997253), you shouldn't disable it. I can't really seem to find any survey or benchmarking comparing eager execution to graph execution.

How does performance compare between graph mode and eager execution Tensorflow 2.0? What, if any, are the advantages with using Graph mode in Tensorflow 2.0?

Comment: "How does performance compare between graph mode and eager execution Tensorflow 2.0?" It should be pretty easy to benchmark, it will probably be quite different depending on model, CPU vs GPU, dataset vs feed_dict, etc. Anyway TF 2.x has [`tf.function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/autograph) to run specific code as a graph (see [Effective TensorFlow 2.0](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/effective_tf2)). The main advantages of graph mode, besides compatibility with 1.x, are serialization and portability, I think.