# compute Gradients fro GradCam in tf 2.0

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I have updated my tensorflow in Python from 1.14 to 2.0 . Now I have a problem with gradient computing, in order to see the GradCam visualisation for a layer.

For example with a model named my_cnn_model, that is already fitted on data, for a classification problem with three classes. If I want to "compute the gradCam" for a given layer named "conv2d_3" for example, I would start with the following in 1.14 :

```
layer_conv = my_cnn_model.get_layer( "conv2d_3" )

#I want it with respect to the first class (so 0), because for example it might have been the model prediction for that image, so I check the proba for that class :
final_layer = my_cnn_model.output[:, 0]

#Then I computed the gradients like that :
grads = keras.backend.gradients( final_layer, layer_conv.output )[0]
print(grads)
```

The last statement (print) would say (the shape is specific for the cnn I used but nevermind):

```
Tensor("gradients/max_pooling2d/MaxPool_grad/MaxPoolGrad:0", shape=(?, 76, 76, 64), dtype=float32)
```

Now, when I use tf 2.0 : the grads computing part, so :

```
grads = keras.backend.gradients( final_layer, layer_conv.output )[0]
```

is not working any more, with the error :

```
RuntimeError: tf.gradients is not supported when eager execution is enabled. Use tf.GradientTape instead.
```

I already searched, and found things like

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
...
```

But all the same I get errors, or I couldn't get the same output `Tensor("gradients/max_pooling2d/MaxPool_grad/MaxPoolGrad:0", shape=(?, 76, 76, 64), dtype=float32)`, so the rest of my gradcam function does not work.

How could I compute the `grads`, which of course would be similar to my 1.14 tf env? Do I miss something trivial?

Edit : I used the functionnal API, with my own CNN, or with "Transfer Learning" model already here in tf.keras, with modified/added layers at the top.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not interested in eager mode, like using old code all around, you can simply disable eager execution.

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53429896/how-do-i-disable-tensorflows-eager-execution):

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```

If, on the other hand, you want to keep eager mode on, of if another thing is troubling your code, you can instead:

```
#you need a persistent tape if you're calling many gradients instead of just one
with tf.GradientTape(persistent = True) as tape:

    #must "watch" all variables that are not "trainable weights" 
    #if you are using them for gradients
    tape.watch(layer_conv.output)

    #if the input data should be watched (you're getting the gradients related to the inputs)
    input_tensor = tf.constant(input_data)
    tape.watch(input_tensor)

    #must do the entire prediction inside this tape block.
    #it would be better if you could make your model output all tensors of interest
    #not sure if you can do "some_layer.output" in eager mode for this purpose
    model_outputs = model(input_tensor) 

#finally, outside the block you can get the gradients
g1 = tape.gradient(model_outputs, layer_conv.output) 
    #again, maybe you need this layer output to be "actually output" 
    #instead of gotten from the layer like this

g2 = tape.gradient(some_output, input_tensor)

g3...
g4...

#finally delete the persistent tape
del tape
```

Comment: Thanks, your first and simplest solution, which I had already used, worked perfectly. For now, I still get problems/errors with the second, which is the "real" solution since it uses tf 2.0 "as default". Once I am able to get my script for GradCam work with tf 2.0, I will also post it as another answer if someone else is interested.

Comment: @hellowolrd have you able to compute GradCAM in tf2.0? I wish to make my model to output the heatmap for production inference time.