# How can I load tensorflow datasets without using eager execution?

Tags: python, tensorflow, data-science

How can I load a list of tensorflow datasets without using eager execution?

I have a list of filepaths that point to saved tensorflow datasets. I also have the element_specs for each path. I want to load each dataset and interleave the result, but I am unable to loop through the element specs.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Create data1 and save
data1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(([3, 4], [0, 1]))
print(list(data1.as_numpy_iterator()))
data1.save(path='1')

# Create data2 and save
data2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(([5, 6], [2, 3]))
print(list(data2.as_numpy_iterator()))
data2.save(path='2')

# Create dataset
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(['1', '2'])

# Create dict of element specs
elem_specs = {0: data1.element_spec, 1: data2.element_spec}

# Enumerate the dataset
dataset = dataset.enumerate()

# I can loop through and load using eager execution
for i, ds in dataset:
    result = tf.data.Dataset.load(ds, element_spec=elem_specs[i.numpy()])

# But if I try with map or interleave, it errors
result = dataset.interleave(lambda i, item: tf.data.Dataset.load(item, element_spec=elem_specs[i]))

# TypeError: Tensor is unhashable. Instead, use tensor.ref() as the key.
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I also tried creating the dict with tensor keys, namely `tf.constant(0).ref()` and `tf.constant(1).ref()`. But still when enumerating, using `i.ref()` doesn't match the dictionary key.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I disable TensorFlow's eager execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53429896/how-do-i-disable-tensorflows-eager-execution)

Comment: No, I already have eager execution disabled by using the map function. I want to keep the map and execute as a graph for performance